# i make condition on the value of userdefaults but the condition never met ? swift 4 Xcode 10

Tags: swift, xcode

as in the title i make condition on the value of userdefaults but the condition never met i tried to change the location and the name and everything but never succeed and this is my code

```
if let UDefault = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "name") as? String {

       // for testing 
        print("from did load \(UDefault)")

        if UDefault == "mike" {

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "go", sender: self)
        }

    }
```

so simple and i think it's correct logically

Comment: Did you save the value correctly ? And what’s the error return or the value returned , try to remove as string and debug to check what’s returned back

Comment: when i tried to print the value its print it correctly

Comment: but the condition which is performSegue never happen !!!

Comment: What’s the problem then

Comment: Can you show us what is being printed? Copy + Paste?

Comment: Does it return false when u try == mike ?

Comment: W1009 08:37:39.743808       1 commandlineflags.cc:1503] Ignoring RegisterValidateFunction() for flag pointer 0x104e8bb00: no flag found at that address
from did load mike

Comment: this is from my debug area

Comment: how you set value for this? can u please add that code also?

Comment: Unrelated but there is a `string(forKey` method.

Answer (score -1):

ok finally after one thousand experiments i found the solution

declare variable called loggingKey above the viewDidLoad

then for the userDefaults i make it string instead of bool value and assign "yes" to it

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("yes", forKey: self.loggingKey )
```

you can assign whatever you want 
and for check for the value i use this following code

```
if let loginStatus = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: loggingKey ) {

        if loginStatus == "yes" {

            performSegue(withIdentifier: "", sender: self)

        }
    }
```

i hope this gonna help someone in future